# Setting up SVN in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have created a SVN repository using this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion. Exactly as per mentioned with two users. Now I want to use Eclipse and add the repository I have on my drive. Can anybody help?

Comment: Check out the Subclipse, svn plugin for eclipse.

Comment: Step by step installation guide for subclipse http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA

Answer (score 2):

Get [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) to add subversion support to eclipse. Then you can checkout from your local subversion server using eclipse's version control / team functionalities.

Comment: i have installed that collabration package which comprises of eclipse mylyn and svn. can that help ???

Comment: that sounds like it should work too, yes. look at the eclipse documentation on how to checkout / use the team functionality. you should see subversion in addition to cvs for all team functionality related stuff

Answer (score 1):

See this [How to use Subversion with Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, try Subclipse. Then use "File->Import...->SVN->Checkout Projects from SVN"

Answer (score 0):

You should install some SVN plugin to Eclipse (e.g.: Subclipse) then you could add your java project in normal way and you'll see SVN ability

Comment: i have installed subeclipse.the plugin works fine.but while adding the repository url error comes.please help